# Get normalised value counts weighted by another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this in Pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'org': ['A1', 'B1', 'A1', 'B2'], 
  'DIH': [True, False, True, False], 
  'Quantity': [10,20,10,20], 
  'Items': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})
```

Now I want to get the value counts and modal value of `Quantity`, but weighted by the number of `Items`.

So I know that I can do

```
df.groupby('Quantity').agg({'Items': 'sum'}).sort_values('Items', ascending=False)
```

And get this:

```
Quantity    Items
20          6
10          4
```

But how do I get this as a percentage value, like this?

```
Quantity    Items
20          60
10          40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more line to your code:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Quantity').agg({'Items': 'sum'}).sort_values('Items', ascending=False)
df2['Items']=(df2['Items']*100)/df2['Items'].sum()

print (df2)
Output :
              Items
Quantity       
20         60.0
10         40.0
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
df.groupby('Quantity').agg({'Items': 'sum'}).sort_values('Items', ascending=False)/df['Items'].sum()*100
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's of some interest, here a function that take a dataframe as input and output a weighted value counts (normalized or not).

```
def weighted_value_counts(x, *args, **kwargs):
    normalize = kwargs.get('normalize', False)
    c0 = x.columns[0]
    c1 = x.columns[1]
    xtmp = x[[c0,c1]].groupby(c0).agg({c1:'sum'}).sort_values(c1,ascending=False)
    s = pd.Series(index=xtmp.index, data=xtmp[c1], name=c0)
    if normalize:
        s = s / x[c1].sum()
    return s
```

Using the example of the question, where the weights are in the column `Item`.
You can obtain your weighted normalized value counts by doing:

```
weighted_value_counts(df[['Quantity','Item']], normalize=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead (one line) :

```
df.groupby('Quantity').agg({'Items': 'sum'}).sort_values('Items', ascending=False).apply(lambda x: 100*x/float(x.sum()))
```